# What is the proper way to say `#` to other developers?

Tags: java, c++, sql, syntax, semantics

I'm trying to improve the clarity of my communication with other developers.

There has been times I've found when I'm describing to other developers to use the `#` symbol in code and found that I hesitate then say its name three different ways. I say pound, hashtag and octothorpe (but it doesn't stop there, as it's sometimes sharp in the case of music and C#).

Some examples of its use are in C++ for includes, used in SQL for comments, and used in Java's EL as `#{}`

I like things to be done simply and consistently. I am curious if there is a standard way (or more universal way) of referencing the symbol by name, and if so what it is. Or is there a different standard for referencing it by different languages, or even SQL?

Comment: I've never heard "octotroph", I have heard ["octothorpe"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octothorpe), though.

Comment: `Why do Java Programmers wear glasses? Because they don't C#.`

Comment: I don't see how this is opinion based. Except in the case of C# I've never in many many years programming heard it called anything except "hash".

Comment: I marked it opinion-based because there is no one, single, factually-correct way to answer this. The reason you use one over another is primarily cultural: as a Brit, I would never say "pound", but I can't argue that is any more correct than one can argue that driving on the left- or right-hand side of the road is "correct".

Comment: @TimB: Well, your experience does not match mine. I've heard it called pound more than anything else.

Comment: How is it possibly called pound? Pound is £

Comment: I guess programming and/or communications were a lot less international when I learned to program, when there was no conceivable answer to this question other than "pound sign".  I'm not sure when, or how completely, the pronunciation of that changed to "hash".  I'd need to look up "octotroph" (never heard it before your question).

Comment: @TimB: That's an understandable perspective for someone from the U.K. Not everybody is from the U.K. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I've heard it called "pound" but "hash" or "hash mark" is way more frequent in my experience. I heard it called "pound" more from Europeans.

Comment: It is starting to sound regional if the non-UK does it differently...but you should all start doing it properly :p

Comment: @xxbbcc: I don't doubt that. Everybody is going to have different experiences. Precisely why this question is opinion-based.

Comment: Andy, thanks for the spelling correction. Benjamin, in the US its pretty common, which I think led to the confusion and this question. I think "hash" as TimB pointed out might be more universal. JSF, I got the term from my thesis adviser, who had his first PhD in mathematics, so it might be Latin based.

Comment: I've heard like people use fences for `#####` and  barbed wire for `********`. If you find code enclosed with `**************** new line code  new line ************` be aware :)

Comment: I was taught that if the symbol preceded a number, it was the *number sign*.  If the symbol follows a number, it represents weight in pounds, such as 4#.  If following a letter, A-G, it represents *sharp*, as in music.  Haven't heard much about why it would be called *hash* though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not pound, that's £

It's not hashtag, that's Twitter.

It is "hash" though. And in the case of the language "sharp".

Comment: It is "hash", as in "please say your name followed by the hash key" when joining a conference call. "sharp" comes from music theory, "sharp and flat". The sharp sign in music is more or less a hash. I imagine this is where the name c sharp comes from.

Comment: @DarrenGourley [indeed, musically-inspired](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/09/07/cnet-history-lesson/)

Comment: Thanks for that interesting tidbit for my train ride home! I also always thought the # came from arranging ++ in to the sharp symbol, but I didn't "c" (sorry) any reference to that!

Comment: I always referred to the symbol `#` as the *number sign*.

Answer (score 1):

It's all based on what you choose to call it where other developers will understand. It's up to the user to decide what you choose to call it and if you are working with others it's up to you guys to have good enough chemistry to know what each other is talking about.